# Invoke soap webservice returning list of objects from java client with axis

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish-3, axis

I'm getting mad with webservices.

I have a very simple soap webservice :

```
@Remote
public interface StudentService
{
public String sayHello();
public List<Student> getStudents();
}
```

And

```
@Stateless
@WebService
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService
{

@Override
public String sayHello()
{
    return "Hello World";
}

public List<Student> getStudents()
{
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    Student st1 = new Student();
    st1.setMatricule(1234);
    st1.setName("student1");
    students.add(st1);

    Student st2 = new Student();
    st2.setMatricule(5678);
    st2.setName("student2");
    students.add(st2);

    return students;
    }
}
```

And

```
public class Student implements Serializable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8286393242028201686L;

private int matricule; 
private String name;

public int getMatricule()
{
    return matricule;
}
public void setMatricule(int matricule)
{
    this.matricule = matricule;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

I deploy the service under glassfish 3.1.

Using the glassfish console, it's working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:getStudentsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://services.tuto.java.com/">
            <return>
                <matricule>1234</matricule>
                <name>student1</name>
            </return>
            <return>
                <matricule>5678</matricule>
                <name>student2</name>
            </return>
        </ns2:getStudentsResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Using php it's also working (for both methods).

Now with a java client :

```
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import org.apache.axis.client.Call;
import org.apache.axis.client.Service;

public class Client
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String endPoint = "http://localhost:8080/StudentServiceImplService/StudentServiceImpl";

    Service service = new Service();
    Call call = (Call) service.createCall();
    call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endPoint));
    call.setOperationName(new QName("http://services.tuto.java.com/","sayHello"));

    System.out.println(call.invoke(new Object[0]));

    Service service2 = new Service();
    Call call2 = (Call) service2.createCall();
    call2.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endPoint));
    call2.setOperationName(new QName("http://services.tuto.java.com/","getStudents"));

    System.out.println(call2.invoke(new Object[0]));
    }
}
```

The first call is working but not the second one.

```
Hello World
12-mars-2012 14:53:23 org.apache.axis.client.Call invoke
GRAVE: Exception:
org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.
at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.onStartChild(SimpleDeserializer.java:145)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:165)
at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:345)
at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
at Client.main(Client.java:24)
```

What can I do ?

After lot of hours searching on internet and trying differents solutions still nothing working ...

Is there a simple solution ?

Thanks.

Edit :

Also tried that :

```
public class SoapClient
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    SOAPMappingRegistry smr = new SOAPMappingRegistry();
    BeanSerializer beanSer = new BeanSerializer();
    smr.mapTypes(Constants.NS_URI_SOAP_ENC,new QName("http://services.tuto.java.com/", "StudentServiceImplService"),Student.class, beanSer, beanSer);       

    Call call = new Call();
    call.setSOAPMappingRegistry(smr);
    call.setEncodingStyleURI(Constants.NS_URI_SOAP_ENC);

    call.setTargetObjectURI("http://services.tuto.java.com/");
    call.setMethodName("getStudents");

    Response resp;
    try
    {
        resp = call.invoke(new URL("http://8h9l45j:8080/StudentServiceImplService/StudentServiceImpl"), "");
    }
    catch (SOAPException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Caught SOAPException (" +
          e.getFaultCode() + "): " + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    if (!resp.generatedFault())
    {
        Parameter ret = resp.getReturnValue();
        Object value = ret.getValue();
        if ( value != null )
        {
            String[] tlist = (String[])value;
            System.out.println();
            for ( int i = 0; i < tlist.length; i++ )
                System.out.println(tlist[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Fault fault = resp.getFault();
        System.err.println("Generated fault: ");
        System.out.println ("  Fault Code   = "
                            + fault.getFaultCode());
        System.out.println ("  Fault String = "
                            + fault.getFaultString());
    }
}
```

With that result :

```
Caught SOAPException (SOAP-ENV:Client): No Deserializer found to deserialize a ':return' using encoding style 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'.
```

Comment: Does Student implement Serializable?

Comment: Try to log the message. According with the error message message is wrong: encountered a child element, which is NOT expected

Comment: Ok, now I understand the meaning of the ':return' --  See edited question for the message -- I tried with a Return class with matricule and name properties, getters and setters.  And changing this line : smr.mapTypes(Constants.NS_URI_SOAP_ENC,new QName("http://services.tuto.java.com/", "return"),Return.class, beanSer, beanSer);  But still not working, same exception.

Comment: How can I do to change in my response soap message the <return> into <student> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First element of response using soap client.

The problem is coming from the maptypes name space : there is no namespace

So now, I have

```
    smr.mapTypes(Constants.NS_URI_SOAP_ENC,new QName("","student"),Student.class, null, new BeanSerializer());  
    smr.mapTypes(Constants.NS_URI_SOAP_ENC,new QName("","matricule"),Integer.class, null, new IntDeserializer());   
    smr.mapTypes(Constants.NS_URI_SOAP_ENC,new QName("","name"),Integer.class, null, new StringDeserializer());
```

And also add

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Student",namespace="http://services.tuto.java.com/")
```

to the Student class to have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:getStudentsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://services.tuto.java.com/">
            <student>
                <matricule>1236</matricule>
                <name>student1</name>
            </student>
            <student>
                <matricule>5678</matricule>
                <name>student2</name>
            </student>
        </ns2:getStudentsResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

The axis client :

```
 public class AxisClient
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
    String endPoint = "http://localhost:8080/StudentServiceImplService/StudentServiceImpl";
    Service service2 = new Service();
    Call call2 = (Call) service2.createCall();
    call2.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endPoint));
    call2.setOperationName(new QName("http://services.tuto.java.com/","getStudents"));
    call2.setReturnType(new QName("","student"), Student.class);
    call2.setReturnType(new QName("", "student"));
    call2.registerTypeMapping(Student.class, new QName("", "student"), null,new BeanDeserializerFactory(Student.class, new QName("", "student")));
    List<Student> students = (List<Student>) call2.invoke(new Object[0]);
    for (Student student : students)
    {
        System.out.println(student);
    }
    }
 }
```

Giving **all** students :

```
Student [matricule=1236, name=student1]
Student [matricule=5678, name=student2]
```

The axis2 client :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String endPoint = "http://localhost:8080/StudentServiceImplService/StudentServiceImpl";

    ServiceClient sc = new ServiceClient();

    Options opts = new Options();
    opts.setTo(new EndpointReference("http://localhost:8080/StudentServiceImplService/StudentServiceImpl"));
    sc.setOptions(opts);

    OMFactory fac = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
    OMNamespace omNs = fac.createOMNamespace("http://services.tuto.java.com/","ns1");

    OMElement method = fac.createOMElement("getStudents", omNs);
    OMElement res = sc.sendReceive(method);
    System.out.println(res);

    Iterator<OMElement> it = res.getChildElements();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
}
```

Giving

```
<ns2:getStudentsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://services.tuto.java.com/"><student><matricule>1236</matricule><name>student1</name></student><student><matricule>5678</matricule><name>student2</name></student></ns2:getStudentsResponse>
<student><matricule>1236</matricule><name>student1</name></student>
<student><matricule>5678</matricule><name>student2</name></student>
```

But I don't know how to deserialize the omelement.

I tried with

```
Student student = (Student) BeanUtil.deserialize(Student.class,res,new DefaultObjectSupplier(),null);
```

but gives me

```
Student [matricule=null, name=null]
```

How can I do ?

Leaving problems :

- don't know how to do the same with axis --OK See before--/axis 2
- the 'resp' (soap client) contains **only first** student

Comment: Don't know how to deserialize the omelement - see edited reposnse.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not get to the WSDL something like

```
http://localhost:8080/StudentServiceImplService/StudentServiceImpl?wsdl
```

and then use axis [wsdl2java](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/ant/axis-wsdl2java.html) to let Axis create the client code for you (which will have all the correct type mappings and namespaces)?

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't use your solution but now my axis client is working.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the SOAP binding style you are using,**RPC/DOCUMENT** ? If you are using RPC then the request and response will be encoded and processed,Axis2 is not supporting the RPC encoded format messages. Try using DOCUMENT SOAP binding style. (I should have put this in comments,kindly bear)

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9598193/752129

Comment: Thanks.  I tried adding @SOAPBinding(style=Style.DOCUMENT, parameterStyle = ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
Both AxisClient and SoapClient are not working.  Same exception.  But I'm using axis and not axis2.